# Are Windows Phone programming questions appropriate for the site?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

Is it appropriate to ask a question about Windows Phone Development on the site? If not, where should I ask such questions?

Comment: Hmm, why did you post that.......? :P

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux Because I anticipate it will be a huge source of off-topic questions, and I wanted to nip this in the bud! :)

Comment: Good idea ;) I understand, I was not knowing, sorry!

Answer (score 21):

**No**, this is not the place for programming questions.

During this site's definition phase, [it was decided](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/windows-phone-developer-questions-should-stay-on-stackoverflow) that the Windows Phone Stack Exchange site should be "**for enthusiasts and power users** of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7". This is similar to the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Development questions still belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 6):

No, these questions are not appropriate for this site.

Per the [faq](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/faq), this site is for the end-user audience.

For developer questions, please check out [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

We have now determined that they belong on Stack Overflow and not here.

Can these get migrated rather than closed? I am using the mobile web version of this site and as far as I can tell they are just getting closed https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/632/connect-to-sql-databse-for-silverlight-app

Please excuse me if they are being migrated and I just can't tell. IMHO closing and not migrating seems a bit rude.

Comment: Seems to have now been migrated :)