# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, scope, top-7

This question is guided by [Robert](http://stackexchange.com/users/92c1c9da-2a26-4604-a58b-ff3795af4920)'s blog post, [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), and the below part is shamelessly [copied from Personal Productivity](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-faq-contain) which copied it from above blog post.

Feel free to list what you think is on-topic or off-topic. Sometimesusing  a separate meta question is useful to discuss things we don't all agree on here. Hence, this is a place for everyone to share what they think belongs or doesn't belong to the scope and see what the community (dis)likes through voting.

---

Much of the FAQ will be somewhat boilerplate: “be nice,” “how to create an account,” “how to ask questions” — it’s all pretty static. Even the sections about “what kind of questions should I (not) ask here?” comes primarily from [the Definition phase of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

But the questions we want to discuss here are those issues specific to our site that need to be mentioned in the FAQ.

Take the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) as an example:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question about:
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> And it is **not about**:
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except in
>     so far as they interface with your
>     computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

It took them almost a year to figure out the list of “we want these sort of questions” and “we don’t want these sort of questions” on Super User. Area 51 gave us a head start but we should also be working out other FAQ-related issues specific to our topic and our community.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Mobile should be off topic. See  [Is Windows Mobile on topic?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic) for the discussion

Answer (score 3):

According to [Are Windows Phone programming questions appropriate for the site?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-windows-phone-programming-questions-appropriate-for-the-site), programming questions are off topic, and belong on StackOverflow. I believe this is already in the FAQ, but I wanted to formally call it out.

**edit**
I also think this should be expanded to marketing, certification and publishing. Perhaps wording around questions and problems end users face while using their phone, and the services around it

Answer (score 3):

As [pocket-pc](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pocket-pc) is related to [windows-mobile](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-mobile), and Windows mobile is now off-topic, Pocket-pc should be too.